# No internet until Wi-Fi panel is opened

Tags: networking, internet, lts, connection, router

I have a curious problem with internet connection on Ubuntu 22.04.

Often while I'm connected to my house Wi-Fi, internet does not work also if the system says the opposite.

The only way I found to fix the problem is to open the Wi-Fi icon on the top right and select the voice "Select Network". When the panel for selecting networks opens, internet does start to work again.
Note that I do not click anything after the panel opens, and note that it says that the Wi-Fi connection is on and stable all the time.

When doing this, it starts to work again, but after not more than a couple minutes, it stops again.

This problem only arises for my Ubuntu PC and only while using my house connection; on other devices it does not do that. Also reinstalling a fresh new OS has not seemed to fix it. I was in fact running Kubuntu just some time ago and I had the same problem.

Furthermore, I do not have changed any network configurations or settings whatsoever.

What can I do to maintain the connection stable as everybody else do?
Thanks :)

**EDIT**

Here is the last lines I see running "sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager", I noted these are somehow periodic:

```
nov 20 21:44:32 KELLO-PC NetworkManager[536]: <info>  [1700513072.6086] dhcp6 (wlp2s0): state changed new lease
nov 20 21:44:33 KELLO-PC NetworkManager[536]: <info>  [1700513073.7577] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): state changed new lease, address=192.168.1.8
nov 20 21:45:02 KELLO-PC NetworkManager[536]: <info>  [1700513102.8283] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> authenticating
nov 20 21:45:02 KELLO-PC NetworkManager[536]: <info>  [1700513102.8301] device (wlp2s0): ip:dhcp4: restarting
nov 20 21:45:02 KELLO-PC NetworkManager[536]: <info>  [1700513102.8570] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): canceled DHCP transaction
nov 20 21:45:02 KELLO-PC NetworkManager[536]: <info>  [1700513102.8571] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
nov 20 21:45:02 KELLO-PC NetworkManager[536]: <info>  [1700513102.8571] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): state changed no lease
nov 20 21:45:02 KELLO-PC NetworkManager[536]: <info>  [1700513102.8574] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
nov 20 21:45:02 KELLO-PC NetworkManager[536]: <info>  [1700513102.8577] device (wlp2s0): ip:dhcp6: restarting
nov 20 21:45:02 KELLO-PC NetworkManager[536]: <info>  [1700513102.8578] dhcp6 (wlp2s0): canceled DHCP transaction
nov 20 21:45:02 KELLO-PC NetworkManager[536]: <info>  [1700513102.8579] dhcp6 (wlp2s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
nov 20 21:45:02 KELLO-PC NetworkManager[536]: <info>  [1700513102.8579] dhcp6 (wlp2s0): state changed no lease
nov 20 21:45:02 KELLO-PC NetworkManager[536]: <info>  [1700513102.8579] dhcp6 (wlp2s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
nov 20 21:45:02 KELLO-PC NetworkManager[536]: <info>  [1700513102.8607] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
nov 20 21:45:02 KELLO-PC NetworkManager[536]: <info>  [1700513102.8618] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
nov 20 21:45:02 KELLO-PC NetworkManager[536]: <info>  [1700513102.8790] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> 4way_handshake
nov 20 21:45:02 KELLO-PC NetworkManager[536]: <info>  [1700513102.9429] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: 4way_handshake -> completed
nov 20 21:45:03 KELLO-PC NetworkManager[536]: <info>  [1700513103.8599] dhcp6 (wlp2s0): state changed new lease
nov 20 21:45:05 KELLO-PC NetworkManager[536]: <info>  [1700513105.0028] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): state changed new lease, address=192.168.1.8
```

Is there any information that can lead to the source of the problem? Thanks!

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl NetworkManager service`. Also do: `service NetworkManager status` and `service --status-all`.